# Is there a way to specify the recursive behaviour of implicit parameters while still writing a type signature?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

According to the GHC User’s Guide, explicitly bound implicit parameters are only propagated into recursive calls if the function has a type signature, and otherwise, the implicit parameters from the original call are used.

```hs
fu True = ?gn
fu False = let ?gn = not ?gn in fu True
br :: (?sp :: Bool) => Bool -> Bool
br True = ?sp
br False = let ?sp = not ?sp in br True
```

```
ghci> let ?gn = True in fu False
True
ghci> let ?sp = True in br False
False
```

However, what if I want to provide a type signature to `fu` while retaining its behaviour? Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a "worker-wrapper" transformation: take the recursive part of the function and move it into a local binding. This lets you make the implicit parameters explicit, so the recursive call has no ambiguity.

```hs
fu :: (?gn :: Bool) => Bool -> Bool
fu = go ?gn
    where
        go gn True = gn
        go gn False = go (not gn) True
```

I personally find this version easier to understand anyway.

Comment: Are implicit parameters actually used for anything in wild?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of! Probably because they behave weirdly, per the question

Comment: here's a paper that touches on implicit parameters, their short comings, and alternate ways to handle similar problems. http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf